# Why is cube not appearing from the python code from spinningcube example of OpenGL Superbible 6th, 7th ed

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I ported over the .cpp version of [spinningcube](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/spinnycube/spinnycube.cpp) found there to python for a better understanding of opengl and to create something new.  While I get the same result as the compiled version from the book source code from both 6th and 7ed as the program is the same from the two editions, the program in its current state displays a green screen only.  The book of OpenGl Superbible 7th ed. on page 177 shows a spinning colored cube is supposed to fly around.   Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Update - June 24, 2019 - I have updated the code so that the cube appears, spins, and moves per the excellent code from Rabbid76.  Thank You.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

import time
import math
fullscreen = True

# sys.path.append("../shared")

# from math3d import m3dDegToRad, m3dRotationMatrix44, M3DMatrix44f, m3dLoadIdentity44, \
                                            # m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
                                            # m3dMatrixMultiply44, m3dTransposeMatrix44, \
                                            # m3dRadToDeg

import numpy.matlib 
import numpy as np 

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, \
                                                  glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

from math import cos, sin
from array import array

M3D_PI = 3.14159265358979323846
M3D_PI_DIV_180 = M3D_PI / 180.0
M3D_INV_PI_DIV_180 = 57.2957795130823229

# Translate matrix. Only 4x4 matrices supported
def m3dTranslateMatrix44(m, x, y, z):
    m[12] += x
    m[13] += y
    m[14] += z

def m3dDegToRad(num):
    return (num * M3D_PI_DIV_180)

def m3dRadToDeg(num):
    return (num * M3D_INV_PI_DIV_180)

def m3dOrtho(l, r, t, b, n, f):
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        2/(r-l),      0,            0,            0,
        0,            2/(t-b),      0,            0,
        0,            0,            -2/(f-n),     0,
        -(r+l)/(r-l), -(t+b)/(t-b), -(f+n)/(f-n), 1)

def m3dPerspective(fov_y, aspect, n, f):
    a = aspect
    ta = math.tan( fov_y / 2 )
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        1/(ta*a),  0,     0,              0,
        0,         1/ta,  0,              0,
        0,         0,    -(f+n)/(f-n),   -1,
        0,         0,    -2*f*n/(f-n),    0)

# Creates a 4x4 rotation matrix, takes radians NOT degrees
def m3dRotationMatrix44(m, angle, x, y, z):
    s = sin(angle)
    c = cos(angle)
    mag = float((x * x + y * y + z * z) ** 0.5)

    if mag == 0.0:
        m3dLoadIdentity(m)
        return

    x /= mag
    y /= mag
    z /= mag

    xx = x * x
    yy = y * y
    zz = z * z
    xy = x * y
    yz = y * z
    zx = z * x
    xs = x * s
    ys = y * s
    zs = z * s
    one_c = 1.0 - c

    m[0] = (one_c * xx) + c
    m[1] = (one_c * xy) - zs
    m[2] = (one_c * zx) + ys
    m[3] = 0.0

    m[4] = (one_c * xy) + zs
    m[5] = (one_c * yy) + c
    m[6] = (one_c * yz) - xs
    m[7] = 0.0

    m[8] = (one_c * zx) - ys
    m[9] = (one_c * yz) + xs
    m[10] = (one_c * zz) + c
    m[11]  = 0.0

    m[12] = 0.0
    m[13] = 0.0
    m[14] = 0.0
    m[15] = 1.0

def m3dMultiply(A, B):
    C = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
    for k in range(0, 4):
        for j in range(0, 4):
            C[k*4+j] = A[0*4+j] * B[k*4+0] + A[1*4+j] * B[k*4+1] + \
                       A[2*4+j] * B[k*4+2] + A[3*4+j] * B[k*4+3]
    return C

def translate(tx, ty, tz):
    """creates the matrix equivalent of glTranslate"""
    return np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                     0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 
tx, ty, tz, 1.0], np.float32)

def rotation_matrix(axis, theta):
    """
    Return the rotation matrix associated with counterclockwise rotation about
    the given axis by theta radians.
    """
    axis = np.asarray(axis)
    axis = axis / math.sqrt(np.dot(axis, axis))
    a = math.cos(theta / 2.0)
    b, c, d = -axis * math.sin(theta / 2.0)
    aa, bb, cc, dd = a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d
    bc, ad, ac, ab, bd, cd = b * c, a * d, a * c, a * b, b * d, c * d
    return np.array([[aa + bb - cc - dd, 2 * (bc + ad), 2 * (bd - ac), 0],
                     [2 * (bc - ad), aa + cc - bb - dd, 2 * (cd + ab), 0],
                     [2 * (bd + ac), 2 * (cd - ab), aa + dd - bb - cc, 0],
[0,0,0,1]])

identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

mv_location = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
proj_location = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

many_cubes = False

# Vertex program
vs_source = '''
    #version 410 core                                                  
    in vec4 position;                                                  
    out VS_OUT                                                         
    {                                                                  
        vec4 color;                                                    
    } vs_out;                                                          
    uniform mat4 mv_matrix;                                            
    uniform mat4 proj_matrix;                                          
    void main(void)                                                    
    {                                                                  
        gl_Position = proj_matrix * mv_matrix * position;              
        vs_out.color = position * 2.0 + vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);      
    }                                                                  
'''

# Fragment program
fs_source = '''
    #version 410 core                                                  
    out vec4 color;                                                    
    in VS_OUT                                                          
    {                                                                  
        vec4 color;                                                    
    } fs_in;                                                           
    void main(void)                                                    
    {                                                                  
        color = fs_in.color;                                           
    }                                                                  
'''


def compile_program(vertex_source, fragment_source):

    global mv_location
    global proj_location

    vertex_shader = None
    fragment_shader = None

    if vertex_source:

        vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(vertex_shader, vertex_source)
        glCompileShader(vertex_shader)

        if not glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
                    raise Exception('failed to compile shader "%s":\n%s' % 
                    ('vertex_shader', glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader)))

    if fragment_source:

        fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(fragment_shader, fragment_source)
        glCompileShader(fragment_shader)

        if not glGetShaderiv(fragment_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
                    raise Exception('failed to compile shader "%s":\n%s' % 
                    ('fragment_shader', glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment_shader)))

    program = glCreateProgram()

    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader)
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader)

    glLinkProgram(program)

    mv_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv_matrix");
    proj_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj_matrix");

    vao = GLuint(0)
    glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    vertex_positions = [
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25, -0.25,  0.25,
         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,

         0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25, -0.25,
        -0.25, -0.25,  0.25,

        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
         0.25,  0.25, -0.25,
         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,

         0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25,  0.25,
        -0.25,  0.25, -0.25 ]

    buffer = GLuint(0)
    glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    #ar=numpy.array(vertex_positions, dtype='float32')
    ar=array("f",vertex_positions)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ar.tostring(), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    return program


class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def display(self):
        global mv_location
        global proj_location
        global proj_matrix
        global many_cubes

        currentTime = time.time()

        green = [ 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0 ]
        one = 1.0;

        glViewport(0, 0, int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))


        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);
        glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, one);        

        glUseProgram(compile_program(vs_source, fs_source))

        #proj_matrix = m3dOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -10, 10)
        #proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(50.0*math.pi/180.0, 512/512, 0.1, 1000.0)
        #proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 1000.0);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)

        if (many_cubes == True):

            for i in range(0, 24):
                f = i + currentTime * 0.3;

                mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

                T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0, 0, -4)

                W = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dTranslateMatrix44(W, sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)

                RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(45.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

                RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
                m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(81.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)


                mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(W, m3dMultiply(T, m3dMultiply(RY, RX)))

                # or can multiply with numpy
                #R = np.matmul(np.array(W).reshape(4,4) , np.matmul(np.array(RX).reshape(4,4), np.array(RY).reshape(4,4)))
                #mv_matrix = np.matmul(R, np.array(T).reshape(4,4))


                # third way this could be done
                # T  = np.matrix(translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)).reshape(4,4)
                # W  = np.matrix(translate(sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)).reshape(4,4)
                # RX = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
                # RY = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))
                # mv_matrix = RX * RY * T * W

                glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix)

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

        else:
            f = currentTime * 0.3;

            mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)

            T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0, 0, -4)

            W = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dTranslateMatrix44(W, sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)

            RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(45.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

            RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
            m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, currentTime * m3dDegToRad(81.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

            mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(W, m3dMultiply(T, m3dMultiply(RY, RX)))

            # second way to that can multiply with numpy
            #R = np.matmul(np.array(W).reshape(4,4) , np.matmul(np.array(RX).reshape(4,4), np.array(RY).reshape(4,4)))
            #mv_matrix = np.matmul(R, np.array(T).reshape(4,4))


            # third way this could be done
            # T  = np.matrix(translate(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)).reshape(4,4)
            # W  = np.matrix(translate(sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)).reshape(4,4)
            # RX = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(17.0)))
            # RY = np.matrix(rotation_matrix( [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], currentTime * m3dDegToRad(13.0)))
            # mv_matrix = RX * RY * T * W


            glUniformMatrix4fv(mv_location, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix)

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36)

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        global proj_matrix
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 0.1, 1000.0);

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global many_cubes

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        elif key == b'm' or key == b'M': 

            if (many_cubes == True):
                many_cubes = False
            else:
                many_cubes = True

        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Spinny Cube')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))

    fullscreen = False
    many_cubes = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: I have accepted Rabbid76 fine and amazingly insightful answer.  The added code is superb and this example is well on its way to the intended purpose of what the author intended.  I also have noted the removal of the use of glRotatef and will continue diligence to making this program the spinning cube it was intended to be.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices have to be initialized by the [Identity Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) and ech matrix need its "own" array of data:

```py
identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
```

---

If the projection matrix is the identity matrix, then the geometry has to be in normalized device space. The normalized device space is in range from (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) and form a perfect cube volume. Your geometry is clipped by the far plane of the view volume, because you've set a z translation of -4.0.

Set up an [Orthographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) Matrix, which "increase" the view volume:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

X:    2/(r-l)         0               0               0
y:    0               2/(t-b)         0               0
z:    0               0               -2/(f-n)        0
t:    -(r+l)/(r-l)    -(t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    1
```

```py
def m3dOrtho(l, r, t, b, n, f):
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        2/(r-l),      0,            0,            0,
        0,            2/(t-b),      0,            0,
        0,            0,            -2/(f-n),     0,
        -(r+l)/(r-l), -(t+b)/(t-b), -(f+n)/(f-n), 1)
```

```py
proj_matrix = m3dOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -10, 10)
glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)

mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        m3dTranslateMatrix44(mv_matrix, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0)

        m3dTranslateMatrix44(mv_matrix, sin(2.1 * f) * 0.5, 
                                        cos(1.7 * f) * 0.5, 
                                        sin(1.3 * f) * cos(1.5 * f) * 2.0)
```

---

Further note, that operations like [`glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) and [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) change the current matrix of the deprecated fixed fucntion pipeline  and make no sens at all if you use a shader with your own matrix uniforms.

Note, matrix operations can also be performed by libraries like [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) or [NumPy](https://www.numpy.org/).

---

For 3D objects I recommend to use [Perspective Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection):

```
x:    1/(ta*a)  0     0              0
y:    0         1/ta  0              0
z:    0         0    -(f+n)/(f-n)   -1
t:    0         0    -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

where:

```
a = w / h
ta = tan( fov_y / 2 );

2 * n / (r-l) = 1 / (ta * a)
2 * n / (t-b) = 1 / ta
```

e.g.

```py
import math

def m3dPerspective(fov_y, aspect, n, f):
    a = aspect
    ta = math.tan( fov_y / 2 )
    return (GLfloat * 16)(
        1/(ta*a),  0,     0,              0,
        0,         1/ta,  0,              0,
        0,         0,    -(f+n)/(f-n),   -1,
        0,         0,    -2*f*n/(f-n),    0)
```

```py
proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(50.0*math.pi/180.0, 512/512, 0.1, 1000.0)
glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_location, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)
```